# How to correct cname record issue with openshift applications?

Tags: php, openshift, openshift-php-cartidges

In my Openshift account there are 3 applications created. For these applications I have used `JBOSS(appa)`, `PHP(appb)` and `Ruby(appc)` cartridges.

Following [this](https://blog.openshift.com/custom-url-names-for-your-paas-applications-host-forwarding-and-cnames-the-openshift-way/) document; I had added a custom URL such as `www.myweb.org` on `appa` application. This configuration had been working fine for long time. Now, I wanted to point my application to other application `appb`. For this I removed alias `www.myweb.org` from `appa` and following same document I executed all configuration steps for `appb`.

**Problem**

`www.myweb.org` is not accessible.

**What I have done**

For my testing I configured another another sub domain `wed.myweb.org` on the same `appb`. This domain works correctly and site is accessible with this new sub domian and URL.

I have checked [Dig web interface](http://digwebinterface.com/); this `www.myweb.org` is pointing to correct application URL from Openshift server as cname record.

Please provide some pointer for debugging the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's not about DNS change propagation? If the domain names you posted are real, www.myweb.org works just fine (and I am pretty sure it would for you too by now).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am very much sure that, this is not about change propagation. These URL are not real.

Comment: where exactly do you get the "is not accessible" from? Can you check the deployment log from the gear too?